# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' from ROS Tutorial

Tags: ros, syntax, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently trying to follow the Gentle Intro to ROS tutorial. I'm attempting to complete chapter 3 and follow these comands

```
int main (int argc , char ∗∗ argv ) {
8 // Ini t i a l i z e the ROS system.
9 r o s : : i n i t ( argc , argv , " he l l o_r o s " ) ;
10
11 // Establ ish thi s program as a ROS node .
12 r o s : : NodeHandle nh ;
13
14 // Send some output as a log message .
15 ROS_INFO_STREAM( "Hel lo , ␣ROS! " ) ;
```

My actual commands in ubuntu are:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){ros::init(argc, argv, "hello_ros");ros::NodeHandle nh;                                            ROS_INFO_STREAM("Hello, ROS!") ;}
```

Which is exactly what the tutorial says but my terminal keeps returning the error

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Please Please help

---

[Originally posted]([https://answers.ros.org/question/215064/bash:-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-`('-from-ros-tutorial/)](https://answers.ros.org/question/215064/bash:-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-%60(%27-from-ros-tutorial/)) by [uzoayo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23429/uzoayo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you directly copy/paste the text from the PDF to your source file?

If so, that is most likely the cause of your problem: the PDF uses markup and character codes that are not valid C++. You can either download the examples in a workable format from the AGITR [website](https://cse.sc.edu//%7Ejokane/agitr/), or copy them by really typing everything manually.

---

Edit:

> Which is exactly what the tutorial says but my terminal keeps returning the error

> ```
> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
> ```

Just for completeness: the book teaches you how to work with ROS by taking you through a set of exercises that get you to write **C++ programs**. I may be wrong, but your last comment seems to suggest you are trying to enter C++ statements directly into the terminal (bash). That won't work, you will have to create a set of source files with a text editor and compile them.

As section 1.2 explains, *A Gentle Introduction to ROS* is not an introduction to programming, so you may want to follow some introductory C++ tutorials online, or pick-up a book about it before trying to continue with AGITR.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2